# {Q} Convert the Single Column value into 3 different Column. i.e Number, Char, Symbol

Tags: sql

```
Col1
1
A
@           Number  |   Char   |  Symbol
2       =>   1        A         @
B                2        B     !
!                3        C     $
3                4        D     %
C
$
4
D
%
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LR7v.png)

Comment: Does your table also have an id/rowno/timestamp column to order by?

Comment: what dbms it is?

Comment: This question was ask in interview to my friend

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question with an equally interesting answer.
Here's what would need to happen.
The first column needs to only be a number.
The second needs to be from the next row down.
And the third needs to be 2 down from the number.

I created a temporary table to fill up with testing data.
Here's what this code would look like:

```
Declare @TestData TABLE
(
  Col1       varchar(5)
);

INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select '1'
INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select 'A'
INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select '@'
INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select '2'
INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select 'B'
INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select '!'
INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select '3'
INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select 'C'
INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select '$'
INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select '4'
INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select 'D'
INSERT INTO @TestData (Col1) select '%'

Declare @TestData2 TABLE
(
    Col1    varchar(5),
    myrow   integer
)

INSERT INTO @TestData2 (Col1, myrow) 
select t1.*,
ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) as myrow
from @TestData as t1

select distinct s1.Col1 as 'Number', 
s2.Col1 as 'Char', 
s3.Col1 as 'Symbol' 
from @TestData2 as s1
left join @TestData2 as s2
on s2.myrow = s1.myrow +1
left join @TestData2 as s3
on s3.myrow = s1.myrow +2
where s1.Col1 between '0' and '99999'
```

Here's the result:

| Number | Char | Symbol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | @ |
| 2 | B | ! |
| 3 | C | $ |
| 4 | D | % |